# Google Maps API Android v2 - "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission required with my-location layer enabled

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, mylocationoverlay

I want to show the location of the user on a Google Maps enabling [my-location layer](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29), but this functionality requires the "[ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)" permission to get the location from the GPS.
Is it possible to prevent the [GoogleMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) from trying to get the location from the GPS?

If I remove the permission "[ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)" in the Manifest file, as soon as I try to display the map, the app crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28578): java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at bbj.a(SourceFile:424)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at bbn.a(SourceFile:232)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at maps.al.b.j(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at uh.h(SourceFile:642)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at un.a(SourceFile:399)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at uj.a(SourceFile:158)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at ui.handleMessage(SourceFile:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime(28578):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `LocationSource` pattern to supply your own locations, which could come from whatever. `LocationSource` is an interface, which you would implement on some object that can supply location data. You register this with `setLocationSource()` on the `GoogleMap`. You implement `activate()` and `deactivate()` methods on your `LocationSource` that will get called to let you know when you should start and stop pushing over locations. As you get location fixes in, you call `onLocationChanged()` on a supplied `OnLocationChangedListener`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Location) demonstrates the use of `LocationSource`.

Comment: Now Google recommends to use GoogleApiClient to deal with locations. Here I have an open question with a bounty to award: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to prevent the GoogleMap from trying to get the location from the GPS?

Default implmentation of `LocationSource` doesn't necessarily have to use GPS to return accurate locations.

> If I remove the permission "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" in the Manifest file, as soon as I try to display the map, the app crashes

This is because the default implementation uses `LocationClient` with `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`.

For now you can do nothing more than following CommonsWare's answer, but I also encourage you to create a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2), so the default implementation doesn't fail when doing `GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled` when you request only `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission, but switches to `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`.

Comment: Now Google recommends to use GoogleApiClient to deal with locations. Here I have an open question with a bounty to award: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage