# Got an error message Using Android Location Services Mock Locations

Tags: android, testing, google-play-services, android-location

i'm developing an Android Application and i need to test my app using Mock Locations, going out at 5AM with almost 0ºC isnt reaaly a good idea!!. I'm using Google Play services Location API,

So, i read Google Documentation and made all the requirements to use Mock Locations.

1 - Add ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission on Manifest -

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

2 - Check the box in Developers Options to "Allow mock Location.

3- Turn on Mock Mode with mLocationClinet.setMockMode(true);

But, in execution time, i got the next error when setMockMode is executed.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission to perform mock operations.
```

Anyone with a similar problem? ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089141/google-maps-api-android-v2-access-fine-location-permission-required-with-my

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be [`uses-permission`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html), not `permission`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: well... what a noobie mistake :|